# Show only first number before point sign

Tags: excel

I have the following simple Excel spreadsheet with the following numbers in column A:

```
         A         B           
1      209.99
2     1451.99
3      354.50
4       23.85
```

Now I want that in column B only the first number before the the point appears so it looks like this:

```
         A         B           
1      209.99      9
2     1451.99      1
3      354.50      4
4       23.85      3
```

Is there a formula which I can use to only get the first number before the point. I tried the MID function but it only works if the numbers always have the same length but in my case the length differs since I have numbers between 0 - 10000.

Do you know any formula that could solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer part to remove the ".xx" part and modulo 10 to get the last digit of the remaining number, so `B1=MOD(INT(A1);10)` should do the job

Documentations:

- [`INT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INT-function-a6c4af9e-356d-4369-ab6a-cb1fd9d343ef)
- [`MOD`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MOD-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3)